# Configuring CiviCRM for 1and1 email limits

Tags: civimail, email

1and1 hosting says: Using the 1&1 mail server, you can send a message with no more than 100 recipients at one time and no more than 200 within five minutes. Please allow 10 seconds between sending e-mail messages.

The 100 batch can be configured in CiviMail, but is there a way to configure "no more than 200 within five minutes" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At **Administer > CiviMail > Mailer Settings** (`civicrm/admin/mail`) you can configure how many mail go out in each mail run. Limit the batch to 100 per run.

Combining your cron schedule with **Administer > Settings > Scheduled Jobs** (`civicrm/admin/job`), you can control the **Run Frequency** for task  **Send Scheduled Mailings**. The options for the this are "every time" or "hourly" (or larger intervals), so you probably want to set "every time" here, and then configure the cron task to be called every three minutes or more.

Scheduled jobs in CiviCRM ([documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.7/initial-set-up/scheduled-jobs/)) are triggered by an external task, for 1and1 customers via [SSH to the hosting account](http://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/scripts-and-programming-languages-c85099/cron-jobs-c37727/explanation-of-cron-jobs-a595881.html). This is where you'll most likely dictate the frequency at which your scheduled jobs may be run.

With all that done, your CiviMail should stay under the limits ... unless additional emails are generated as well. What happens if you hit that limit - say if your CRM is partway through a mailout - and a donor's receipt or password reset email gets trashed for being email number 101 or 102? It might not be likely, but only your org can decide if it's acceptable, and you'll never know for sure how much buffer to allow.

So, the above configuration can mostly avoid hitting 1and1's limits. But ... please see my other answer :)

Answer (score 1):

*Disclosure: my employer offers hosting, so I have a horse in this race. But I'm not here to sell you our services.*

**Get a hosting environment which supports what you want to do.** Rather than adjusting your CRM to fit your hosting environment, you should adjust your hosting to fit your needs. I've genuinely seen people spend thousands of dollars on development and tweaking trying to make budget hosting environments work, and it's painful to watch.

It's possible 1and1 do have a plan that supports using CiviMail, so do ask what your options are with your existing host. If they don't, there are plenty of hosting environments that do, and there's a list of them on the civicrm.org website: https://civicrm.org/hosting-providers

Comment: The ten seconds part may be an issue ... 200/5min = 2400/hr which might be fine unless you want to deliver a large mail burst *fast*. Really depends on your org's needs whether those requirements will be a challenge. If they are, there are some mail providers who you can send over HTTP(s) with, so you may be able to stick with 1and1 yet.

Comment: Please vote for the other answer, not this one ... that answer actually answers the question at hand, not a meta-question 